# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Didn't send enough!' on testing contract

Tags: hardhat, testing, unittesting, chai, revert

Getting this error while testing one of functions functionality in the contract

```
AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with You need to spend more ETH!!, but other exception was thrown: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Didn't send enough!'
```

I have used waffles chai-matchers.
This is my test.js

```js
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")

describe("FundMe", function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    beforeEach(async function () {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]) 
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer) 
    describe("fund", function () {
        it("Fails if you don't send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more ETH!!"
            )
        })
    })
})
```

this is my FundMe.sol contract's fund function

```
function fund() public payable {
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
            "Didn't send enough!"
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error because in my fundMe smart contract i used revert error in require is different than script, they both should be same.
In require it is "Didn't send enough!" while in revert it is "You need to spend more ETH!!"
So i have to make them same then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You must expect this, because smart contract will revert `VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string` + `YOUR_ERROR_MESSAGE`

```
await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith("VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Didn't send enough!'")
```